# Langchain4j with downloaded LLM

Tags: java, langchain, large-language-model, stable-diffusion

I am exploring Langchain4j. I want to use it to interact with the downloaded model locally.

I have downloaded stable-diffusion model from Huggingface using this command:

```
git lfs clone https://huggingface.co/stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0
```

How can I use Langchain4j(with stable-diffusion) to create an Image in my local?
Does Langchain4j have that capability currently?